# Defining custom typings.d.ts don't solve the problem of importing js library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, parse-server

I'm trying to use [Parse-server JS sdk](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/) in a angular 8 application.
But it doesn't matter what strategy I use I get errors like.

I tried:

- Custom typings.d.ts files with `declare var parse: any;`
- installed the @types/parse
- importing with `import * as parse from 'parse'` or `import parse from 'parse'`
- tried all the suggestions from [angular help - Using Published Libraries](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries)

> ERROR in node_modules/@types/parse/index.d.ts:498:14 - error TS2456: Type alias 'Encode' circularly references itself.

Here there is an stackblitz with the  package that I'm trying to use.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzapp7

On stackblitz it's giving other error, but on vscode all errors is from this `Encode` thing.

How can I just tell to angular/vscode to ignore all these things and just let me code without autocompletion or typing checking for the parse import.

Comment: What version of typescript are you on?

Comment: @AluanHaddad ~3.5.3

Comment: @Reactgular That worked, that possibility didn't occured to me in any possible moment. the version 2.10.0 worked. Thanks man, add you comment as answer, so I can flag as accepted answer. ps: nice name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the version of `@types/parse` matches the version of `parse` package which you're using.

Often the `@types` definitions are behind on releases, and they are auto-generated so there can be bugs. If you find a bug, then you can open an issue on the `@types` project and ask someone to fix it.

The alternative is to uninstall `@types/parse` and work with the library without type definitions